# Favicon not working when uploaded but working well on localhost

Tags: html, favicon

I made a website with a favicon that was working a few days ago. Now, it is only working on my localhost. It's not appearing online. What could be the problem? I uploaded the favicon to public_html.

```
<link href="view/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="view/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico' />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try again after clearing the browser cache..or if you can, open the website from an incognito window..

Comment: Can you share a link to the site or no?

Comment: Make sure that you clean browser cache. Also it is wise to use absolute path like `/favicon.ico`.